# Programa Meses del año

Tags: c++

Debo hacer un programa en C ++ que muestre en pantalla los meses que tienen treinta días, lo hice mediante matrices porque eso me pidieron también. Utilicé un ciclo `for` anidado para determinar en que posiciones de fila y columna (las filas son los meses y las columnas el número de días).

Para saber si el valor es treinta, utilicé un condicional para esta tarea y puse que si la en una posición de fila y columna el valor es 30, me muestre en pantalla esa posición de fila y columna pero lo que hace el programa es devolverme el numero treinta es vez de la posición, no sé que puedo mejorar o qué estoy haciendo mal.

Adjunto lo que hice para que se se entienda mejor:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {    
    int DiasMes[12][2];
    DiasMes[1][2]=31;
    DiasMes[2][2]=28;
    DiasMes[3][2]=31;
    DiasMes[4][2]=30;
    DiasMes[5][2]=31;
    DiasMes[6][2]=30;
    DiasMes[7][2]=31;
    DiasMes[8][2]=31;
    DiasMes[9][2]=30;
    DiasMes[10][2]=31;
    DiasMes[11][2]=30;
    DiasMes[12][2]=31;
    
    for(int f=0;f<13;f++){
        for(int c=0;c<2;c++)
            if (DiasMes[f][c]==30){
                cout<<DiasMes[f][c]<<endl;
            }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No necesitas un `Array` (dos dimensiones) para lo que pretendes hacer, con un vector (lista) de 12 elementos es más que suficiente. Por otro lado, recuerda que las estructuras de tipo `Array` se enumeran desde cero (0) y no desde uno (1). Saludos

Comment: Lo que tendrás que hacer si quieres que te imprima la posición, es no imprimir el contenido `DiasMes[f][c]`, sino la f y la c, que es la posición del elemento.

Answer (score 6):

Esto no hace lo que crees que hace:

```
int DiasMes[12][2];
```

Ahí estás definiendo una formación de 24 enteros (12 filas multiplicado por 2 columnas), es decir, algo así:

|  | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  |  |
| 1 |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |
| 4 |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |
| 6 |  |  |
| 7 |  |  |
| 8 |  |  |
| 9 |  |  |
| 10 |  |  |
| 11 |  |  |

Por cierto, ni siquiera estás escribiendo valores dentro de la formación, fíjate que la primera columna está indizada en cero (`0`) y la segunda en uno (`1`), en cambio tú escribes en la columna dos (`2`) que sería la tercera:

```
int DiasMes[12][2];
DiasMes[1][2]=31;  // ¡Mal! la tercera columna (índice 2) ¡no existe!
DiasMes[2][2]=28;  // ¡Mal! la tercera columna (índice 2) ¡no existe!
DiasMes[3][2]=31;  // ¡Mal! la tercera columna (índice 2) ¡no existe!
DiasMes[4][2]=30;  // ¡Mal! la tercera columna (índice 2) ¡no existe!
DiasMes[5][2]=31;  // ¡Mal! la tercera columna (índice 2) ¡no existe!
DiasMes[6][2]=30;  // ¡Mal! la tercera columna (índice 2) ¡no existe!
DiasMes[7][2]=31;  // ¡Mal! la tercera columna (índice 2) ¡no existe!
DiasMes[8][2]=31;  // ¡Mal! la tercera columna (índice 2) ¡no existe!
DiasMes[9][2]=30;  // ¡Mal! la tercera columna (índice 2) ¡no existe!
DiasMes[10][2]=31; // ¡Mal! la tercera columna (índice 2) ¡no existe!
DiasMes[11][2]=30; // ¡Mal! la tercera columna (índice 2) ¡no existe!
DiasMes[12][2]=31; // ¡Mal! la tercera columna (índice 2) ¡no existe!
```

Este error podría provocarte fallos en tiempo de ejecución. Lo que en realidad necesitas es una formación de 12 elementos:

```
int DiasMes[12];
```

> Utilicé un ciclo `for` anidado para determinar en que posiciones de fila y columna (las filas son los meses y las columnas el número de días).

No es necesario, ya que sólo necesitas una fila.

> Lo que hace el programa es devolverme el numero treinta es vez de la posición.

Obviamente, pues es exáctamente lo que le pediste:

```
if (DiasMes[f][c]==30){
//         ^^^^^^  ^^ <-- Si la posición 'f', 'c' es treinta...
    cout<<DiasMes[f][c]<<endl; // <-- Muestra lo contenido en la posición 'f', 'c'...
                               // que siempre será treinta, porque no imprimirás en caso contrario
}
```

Posiblemente querías hacer esto:

```
if (DiasMes[f][c]==30){
    cout << "El mes en la fila " << f << " columna " << c " es de " << DiasMes[f][c] << " dias.\n";
}
```

Si en lugar de una formación de dos dimensiones usamos, como debe ser, una de una dimensión, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // Usa esta cláusula siempre en el ámbito más pequeño posible.
    using namespace std;

    int DiasMes[12] = {
        31, // 1
        28, // 2
        31, // 3
        30, // 4
        31, // 5
        30, // 6
        31, // 7
        31, // 8
        30, // 9
        31, // 10
        30, // 11
        31  // 12
    }

    for (int mes = 0; mes != 12; ++mes) {
        if (DiasMes[mes] == 30)
            cout << "El mes " << (mes + 1) << " tiene " << DiasMes[mes] << " dias.\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Tal como te digo en [mi comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/476494/programa-meses-del-a%c3%b1o#comment848240_476494), no hace falta que uses una estructura bidimensional para almacenar los datos. Con una lista o vector tienes suficiente. Además, recuerda que las estructuras de tipo arreglo en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) (como en casi todos los lenguajes) comienzan a enumerarse desde el cero (0).

Dicho esto, lo primero es declarar el vector de 12 elementos con datos tipo entero (`int`) que representarán el número de días de un mes:

```cpp
int diasMes[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
```

O bien puedes iniciarlo como lo tienes en tu código, ya que te ayuda a mantener la relación visual entre el número de meses y los días:

```cpp
int diasMes[12];
diasMes[0] = 31;  // Enero
diasMes[1] = 28;  // Febrero (no bisiesto)
diasMes[2] = 31;  // Marzo
diasMes[3] = 30;  // Abril
diasMes[4] = 31;  // Mayo
diasMes[5] = 30;  // Junio
diasMes[6] = 31;  // Julio
diasMes[7] = 31;  // Agosto
diasMes[8] = 30;  // Septiembre
diasMes[9] = 31;  // Octubre
diasMes[10] = 30; // Noviembre
diasMes[11] = 31; // Diciembre
```

Como puedes observar, el vector tiene 12 posiciones que van desde el 0 hasta el 11.

Ahora sólo necesitas un bucle `for` para recorrer el vector, y en vez de imprimir el valor del elemento vas a mostrar el índice. Es decir, cuando recorres un iterable, tienes una variable (usualmente `i`) que indica qué iteración estás realizando. Es este valor el que vas a mostrar por pantalla, y no el elemento del vector en dicha posición.

Por ejemplo:

```cpp
for(int mes = 0; mes < 12; mes++){
  if(diasMes[mes] == 30) {
    // el índice de una lista va desde 0, por lo cual
    // para mostrar los meses desde 1 hasta 12 debemos
    // sumar 1 al valor del índice
    std::cout << mes + 1 << endl;
  }
}
```

Como puedes observar, estoy llamando `mes` a la variable del iterando. Esta variable indica en qué posición o iteración me encuentro dentro del bucle y es precisamente la que corresponde con el mes que deseo obtener.

Como el iterador empieza en 0 y termina en 11, y yo deseo mostrar el número del mes en la numeración estándar (1 al 12) debemos sumar 1 al iterando, para que la salida sea la esperada.

El código final podría quedar así:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int diasMes[12];
    diasMes[0] = 31;
    diasMes[1] = 28;
    diasMes[2] = 31;
    diasMes[3] = 30;
    diasMes[4] = 31;
    diasMes[5] = 30;
    diasMes[6] = 31;
    diasMes[7] = 31;
    diasMes[8] = 30;
    diasMes[9] = 31;
    diasMes[10] = 30;
    diasMes[11] = 31;

    for(int mes = 0; mes < 12; mes++){
      if(diasMes[mes] == 30) {
        // el índice de una lista empieza en 0, por lo cual
        // para mostrar los meses desde 1 hasta 12 debemos
        // sumar 1 al valor del índice
        std::cout << mes + 1 << endl;
      }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Como nota final, cuando elijas nombres de variables, intenta que las mismas sean lo suficientemente explícitas para que se entienda lo que estás haciendo. Reserva el uso de nombres que empiezan con mayúscula para las Clases. Es por ello que en mi código he cambiado el nombre de `DiasMes` por `diasMes`. Más información [en la guía de estilos](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#nl8-use-a-consistent-naming-style).